# How to destroy variables instantiated in fragment after user logs out

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

I have to pull data from server for the first time when user lands on the *fragment* and then data should persist in the application unless user logs out but I tried this way.

```
 public class AttendanceFragment : Fragment
{
    private static ListView listView;
    private static ProgressBar progress;
    private static List<DA_ClassSectionAttendance> dataList=new List<DA_ClassSectionAttendance>(); 

// If i instantiate this variable 'dataList' here 
//it will be persisted even the user logs out I know its declared as static
// because I am accessing this variable  on broadcast receiver.
// But I want this re-instantiated after user logs out but HOW?
    private static AttendanceListAdapter attendanceAdapter;
    private static DA_Attendance daAttendance;
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      //  dataList = new List<DA_ClassSectionAttendance>(); if I instantiate this variable here everytime this fragment created or restores dataList.Count is zero or null 
        attendanceAdapter = new AttendanceListAdapter(this.Activity, dataList);
        if((dataList==null || dataList.Count==0)) // pull data from server for the first time when fragment is created but I want this method call when user logs out as well.
           {
                GetClassSection(); // this method pulls data from server

            }  

        //set whether MenuOption show/hide from toolbar
        HasOptionsMenu = true;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Mutable static variables are bad practice in Android anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can release the variables in onDestroy of the fragment. If you need to persist the data then you need to save it in DB. You can use SQLlite or realDB based on your requirement. Then when user logs out, clear the DB at that time. Hope it clears